# Why did the Operator hang up after Agent Tucker said "18 Inches"?

Tags: dialogue, johnny-english-reborn

In *Johnny English Reborn*, after Agent Tucket says to the operator that the altitude of the helicopter is 18 inches, why did she hang up on him?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably because the operator thought it was a **prank emergency call.**

A helicopter at 18 inches of altitude is very close to the ground and thats a very unusual emergency.

Obviously, (out of universe) it's intended as a *joke* and to give us the driving a helicopter like a car scene.

Comment: What I meant is that did the Operator think that Tucker meant something Sexual? Because I found this in the "sex and nudity" category on Imdb parents guide and I just wonder.